# How to re install Windows 7 (64bit) without a resource CD and without internetand get all the drivers installed?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, reinstall, drivers, windows-7-restore

I spent half a day trying the different choices I have to re install Windows 7. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bt edition. The OS came with the laptop. So, I never changed it and of course I don't have the resource CD to re-install.

I got another Windows 7 from a friend and tried to upgrade the old version. It was successful except that, at the end it asked me a key. But, I was able to login by checking (key will be registered online ...bla bla)... but guess what, the some drivers are not installed ... of course the basic one (for me), network driver, is not even installed. So, I couldn't go online and do my job.

The good thing is I had Ubuntu installed on my USB and on the hard drive. And I am able to access the one which is on a USB ..Not the one in the hard drive because it is not showing me the option to select it at start up.

I tried to download a driver detective software from Ubuntu, saved on on the hard disk and try to access it from Windows ..and it is not working..

Unless I get an Internet connection from the Windows side I will not be able to do some tasks. I just started using Ubuntu 3 days ago and I am really having a hard time even installing softwares.

Can any body help me out what to do in order to get at least my network driver work so that I can use Internet? Thats all I need for now. Thank you for your time.

FYI: I didnt have a restore point so I couldnt do that neither. I tried to go to Control Panel->Advanced Settings-> in order to restore it. It asked me a Windows CD I supplied one of those CD'S but it couldnt recognize one of them.

Comment: You can probably find your network driver from your laptop vendor's support site. Otherwise, you may be able to find the name through the output of the `dmesg` command.

Comment: I would go with the first option. But, do you think if I downloaded the drivers from Ubuntu OS and save it in external hard disk (USB), do you think it will run on the Windows? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ubuntu, or Linux in general, uses a completely different driver interface so they won't be compatible with Windows. Most vendors only provide Windows drivers anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already got the solution for it.

1) Restart the computer. While booting up press and hold 0. It will bring you a guide (steps ) to format your PC and put it in a state when you bought the laptop without the resource CD.

But Caution..it will delete all your data and its partitions you created as well.

FYI: My laptop is Toshiba Satellite

Answer (score 0):

Without internet, and without the DVD and without installing drivers? I don't think that leaves much left of an OS.

BTW, System Restore doesn't require the DVD, so you may have picked the wrong option.

If your laptop was activated by the OEm, then you can use an OEM activation Windows DVD to install. But that requires the DVD, and the Internet, and drivers. . .

Comment: thank you for your response. I don't have a system restore point created by so I am unable to use that option. I am planning to go to near by BestBuy stores, if they can give me the resource CD.

Comment: IMO, you should contact your manufacturer for the resource DVD. But the Bestbuy store might have one handy.